# F# XML provider 'System.TypeInitializationException' when writing

Tags: xml, f#, f#-data

I'm having some problems writing through the XML type provider in F# data.

This is the file i'm loading:

```
<authors>
  <science>
    <author name="Paul Feyerabend" born="1924" />
    <author name="Thomas Kuhn" />
  </science>
  <mathematics>
    <author name="Bertrand Russell" />
    <author name="Ludwig Wittgenstein" born="1889" />
    <author name="Alfred North Whitehead" died="1947" />
  </mathematics>
</authors>
```

I have split authors into subcategories so I don't have to rewrite the whole file each time I want to add an author (is this correct or am I missing something?)

And here is the code:

```
open FSharp.Data
open System.IO

type Writers = XmlProvider<"../TestProvider/Writers.xml">

let writers = Writers.Load(File.OpenText("../TestProvider/Writers.xml"))

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv

    Array.append writers.Science.Authors [| Writers.Author("Richard Feynman", Some 1918) |] |> ignore

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

This nets me the following error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in TestProvider.exe
Additional information: The type initializer for '<StartupCode$TestProvider>.$Program' threw an exception.
```

Comment: When you're running the program, is `../TestProvider/Writers.xml` still present at that *relative* path?

Comment: Thanks, it seems it did not like the relative path, however, it is not saving the record to the XML. Is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, I think the exception you're getting is because of your use of a relative path. When you refer to `../TestProvider/Writers.xml`, the compiler will be able to find the file *relative to your code*.

Assuming you use Visual Studio, when it compiles the code, it puts the binaries in `bin/Debug` or `bin/Release`. When you try to run the executable from one of these folders, it's going to expect the files to be in `bin/TestProvider/Writers.xml`, which most likely doesn't exist. This most likely happens when you call `File.OpenText` (you didn't post the full exception, but I'd expect that somewhere in an InnerException, you'd have a message to that effect).

FWIW, if you inline the sample, the following runs without problems:

```
open FSharp.Data

type Writers = XmlProvider<"""<authors>
  <science>
    <author name="Paul Feyerabend" born="1924" />
    <author name="Thomas Kuhn" />
  </science>
  <mathematics>
    <author name="Bertrand Russell" />
    <author name="Ludwig Wittgenstein" born="1889" />
    <author name="Alfred North Whitehead" died="1947" />
  </mathematics>
</authors>""">

let writers = Writers.GetSample()

Array.append writers.Science.Authors [| Writers.Author("Richard Feynman", Some 1918) |] |> ignore
```

This isn't going to make any changes to the file, though.

`writers.Science.Authors` is an array (in memory), and `[| Writers.Author("Richard Feynman", Some 1918) |]` is another array. When you call `Array.append`, it returns *a new* array with the two arrays appended, but due to the use of `ignore`, this new value is immediately thrown away.

A slightly more useful approach would be to first get the resulting new array:

```
> let updatedScientists =
    writers.Science.Authors
    |> Array.append [| Writers.Author("Richard Feynman", Some 1918) |];;

val updatedScientists : XmlProvider<...>.Author [] =
  [|<author name="Richard Feynman" born="1918" />;
    <author name="Paul Feyerabend" born="1924" />;
    <author name="Thomas Kuhn" />|]
```

As you can tell, this only gives you the new `Author` array.

You'll still need to add this back to the `writers` value and write the updated value to the file. That doesn't happen automatically.